# Streaming from IP camera using chromecast

Tags: android, video-streaming, google-cast, chromecast

I am trying to stream through IP camera through my android device.
I have edited the URL from the code posted on [GitHub](https://github.com/googlecast/cast-android-sample) It is streaming on chrome browser when I tried to run from IP address of camera.

But when I try to cast it, It shows me **player status:IDLE** and blank screen on TV

Other videos are playing but for streaming I am facing problem. Any help??

Comment: what format is your stream? Can you watch the same stream in a video element on our desktop chrome browser?

Comment: @AliNaddaf: As through http:// it is playing on chrome browser the format of stream is mp4. And on vlc we can able to stream it through rtsp:// protocol.

Comment: @AliNaddaf: Is live streaming really possible, because we are facing problems on same and which file format are currently supported by chrome-Cast??

Comment: You didn't answer my earlier question: in desktop chrome, can you play that using a <video/> element?

Comment: @AliNaddaf: Since http:// is not working in video element even rtsp:// is not supported by video element yet, so can you suggest me a way??

Comment: There is no easy way around that. Some cameras can provide mjpeg (motion jpeg); I don't know if mjoeg is supported or not, but you can try. You can also just try sending images periodically and try to show them on the chromecast as they come in.

Comment: @AliNaddaf: K thnk u.. I vl try

Comment: @Rohit: I can play mp4(downloaded from youtube) through http in <VIDEO> tag, but I don't think mp4 is capable of "streaming".

Comment: @Li-chihWu: I can also play *.mp4 through video tag but my camera is not supporting mp4..

Comment: @Rohit "streaming" is not supported by mp4, if you want to do "streaming", you need HLS or other supported method.
You should specify what camera you are working at, and what functions it has.