# Possible approaches to stream video from an IP camera to chromecast or raspberry pi

Tags: video-streaming, raspberry-pi, chromecast, onvif

This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20489251/streaming-from-ip-camera-using-chromecast), which is not answered yet.

Basically I want to know if it is possible to:

```
Cast the stream from an IP camera to chromecast or some other devices (like raspberry pi)
```

The IP camera I have is a D-Link one, with some GPL code [downloadable](http://tsd.dlink.com.tw/).
It is also [ONVIF conformant](http://www.onvif.org/FindaProduct/ProfileProducts.aspx).

The vendor solution provides both "cloud" access and iOS / Android app, which makes me think it is possible to write some service and/or an app for it.

I am open to any and all possible approaches for the viewing / casting feature, and I do not need to control the camera (just viewing the video stream on the TV).

Thanks in advance.

---- **UPDATE** ----

I should mention that I can also accept approaches using other devices, like `Raspberry Pi` or what is suggested in [this dlink forum question](http://forums.dlink.com/index.php?topic=59085).

Comment: What is the format(s) of the stream that the camera provides? A good number of cameras provide rtsp which is not supported by Chromecast.

Comment: From the model's datasheet, `HTTP` and `RTP/RTSP/RTCP` is mentioned. also, what is supported by Chromecast (if not `rtsp`)?

Comment: You can find the list of supported content on our developers site. If it provides mp4 over http, you can create a video tag and make the source pointing to your camera's stream and do a quick test to see if it works or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for Chromecast: I'm not an expert on how to feed a video stream on the bundled players but you can make your own Chromecast app that would pull in the video feed and render it. You can get the exact rtsp/http links from  the camera documentation and then all you need is a code to receive/demux/render the stream, I've been involved in making a similar app that plays MJPEG streams on the TV, worked fine.

If you are not bound to Chromecast but can use any embedded device, then Raspberry Pi + [omxplayer](http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/software_utilities/omxplayer) should be a very easy setup. Omxplayer is provided as a Rasbioan package and plays an rtsp link straightforward using hardware acceleration that could be beneficial to big streams. If more than one camera is targeted you can always write an ONVIF client to get the stream url from any ONVIF compliant camera and feed it to the omxplayer.

Comment: [this website](http://www.ispyconnect.com/man.aspx?n=dlink) lists the URL to access the camera.

Comment: @JeffShaw well then if you have ar Raspberry Pi by hand install the omxplayer package and try omxplayer <rtsp url>

Comment: i will need to build from [source](https://github.com/popcornmix/omxplayer/) to use omxplayer, since my raspberry pi uses pacman and omxplayer is not ported. in the meanwhile, URL found [here](http://forums.dlink.com/index.php?topic=57687.0) works in VLC player. Thanks again for the suggestions.